# Why 'su user' as root asking for user 's password in my CentOS 7 machine?

Tags: centos, users, su

In my CentOS 7 laptop while switching from `root` to `user` using `su user` as root, it's asking for `user`'s password.

```
-bash-4.2# su user
 Password:
```

While switching from `root` to other account it's not supposed to ask for password.

I've tried the same in Fedora 27 and another CentOS 7 machine. There `su user` as `root` simply switching the `user` without asking for `user`'s password.

I'm using the repository provided version of `su` only.

Any help regarding why this is happening will be helpful.

**Updates**

Contents of `/etc/pam.d/su` is as follows

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth            sufficient  pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
#auth           sufficient      pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
#auth           required        pam_wheel.so use_uid
auth            substack        system-auth
auth            include         postlogin
account         sufficient  pam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 use_uid quiet
account         include         system-auth
password        include         system-auth
session         include         system-auth
session         include         postlogin
session         optional        pam_xauth.so
```

Comment: does it matter which user you switch to? Do you have something unusual in `/etc/pam.d/su`?

Comment: And when you first switch to `root` you use what command(or you make login on a new tty)? Remember that `sudo -s ` and `sudo -i` as an example create root sessions with and without shell

Comment: @ilkkachu It doesn't matter what user I'm switching to. Even `su nobody` asking for `nobody`'s password which neither has a `shell` access nor a password..!! I've updated the question with `/etc/pam.d/su` file.

Comment: @nwildner I'm changing to `root` using `su -` only. I've tried with `sudo -s` also but the problem is persistent.

Comment: A silly question: Is `root`'s id 0?

Comment: @KarelVlk Yes, `root`'s id is 0 as per `/etc/passwd`..

Comment: @roaima Updated as per community guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved after an regular update using `yum update`. Still it'll be very helpful if I get some insight regarding what may cause this.